# Foreign Key mapping in Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, foreign-keys, primary-key

I understand that Core Data is not a relational database but I need to understand how it can be used to support a client/server model where the server uses a Rails, ActiveRecord, Mysql setup.

My app is pulling records from the server using JSON and I am mapping the relationships using Core Data.

The Foreign Key in the SQLLite database is showing the PK field of the related table even though I have set the User Info Key/Value of primaryAttributeKey => id. (I can't remember where I saw this mentioned.)

Is there any way to setup the models so they will use my id as the PK so that it will clean up the export of related data back to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Edward,

The PK is just a field in your object. If you want to maintain them in CD, they are just numbers. As you build your object graph, you have to maintain them in parallel with your relations. Of course, exporting records created on the device back to your server will have difficulty -- FKs and PKs are unique to each table and that uniqueness is determined on the server. Hence, tracking these numbers is not that useful.

May I suggest that your JSON needs to be structured such that it is redundant -- that it has both the data and the various PKs and FKs, if any?

Finally, you appear to be making a CRUD focused API. Generally, those are low performance APIs for remote devices. There are other problems with CRUD APIs, such as inconsistent business logic between servers and clients. I would suggest you to rethink your APIs.

Andrew